# Copy to clipboard without swf. Only using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create code for copy to clipboard in my web site. but it is based on flash but i need code for copy to clipboard with only jquery and javascript.Because swf not working on Android and iPhone's web browser please help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that's already been answered. [How to copy to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) it's impossible to have a safe cross-browser way to automatically copy to the clipboard.

Comment: i know that but i hope in future this technology will appear.So i post this question.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't think this will ever exist, it doesn't exist for security purposes. Could you imagine if you went to a page and that page could take your clipboard contents or put whatever it wants into your clipboard without your knowledge? I think Internet Explorer might be the only one that allows this.